# Calculate disease prevalence and gender distribution based on lab data

Tags: database, sas, bioinformatics, medical, bigdata

I have a dataset of a patient diagnoses and lab values for a few different labs. To begin exploratory analysis, I would like to calculate disease prevalence and do a gender chi-square for each disease in this group, for have positive values for labs. The issue is that the the diagnoses and lab values are on different lines.

This is an example of what the data looks like:

```
ID  n_lab1  units_lab1  upperlim_lab1   diagnosis   gender  age
1   0.5 nmol/L  0.2 celiac  M   31
1   0.5 nmol/L  0.2 RA  M   31
1   0.5 nmol/L  0.2 Lupus   M   31
1   0.5 nmol/L  0.2 Vitiligo    M   31
1   0.5 nmol/L  0.2 Crohn's M   31
2   0.8 nmol/L  0.2 Uveitis F   52
2   0.8 nmol/L  0.2 RA  F   52
2   0.8 nmol/L  0.2 alopecia    F   52
3   1.5 U/mL    1   hypothyroid F   69
3   1.5 U/mL    1   celiac  F   69
3   1.5 U/mL    1   vitiligo    F   69
3   1.5 U/mL    1   RA  F   69
3   1.5 U/mL    1   scleroderma F   69
```

Each patient has a diagnosis listed on a different line.

The inclusion criteria code would look something like this.

```
IF units_lab1 = "nmol/L" AND upperlim_lab1 = 0.2 AND n_lab1 GE 0.2;
IF units_lab1 = "U/mL" AND upperlim_lab1 = 1 AND n_lab1 GE 1.5;
```

With data that looks like this, how would I go about calculating the prevalence of celiac disease, then RA, etc. and also calculate the gender distribution and perform a chi-square with PROC FREQ; tables /chisq;

Comment: Please post your data as text. To work with this we'd have to type it out, which is not likely.

Comment: @Reeza I have posted the data as text

Comment: What do you mean by diagnosis and lab value are not on the same line? They appear to be as far as I can see...you need to explain your desired logic further, and I would suggest included the desired output for your data. The simplest answer may be a quick transpose of the data, or you may need something more complicated.